# Python melt with same column in id_vars and value_vars

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-melt

I have following dataframe df:

```
data = {'SAP ID': ['MATSAP1', 'MATSAP2'],
    'DESCRIPTION': ['DESC1', 'DESC2'],
    'BASIC': ['BD1', 'BD2'],
    'LINK': ['MD1', 'MD2']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to melt the df and have the following output:
[image]

However, on using the below code, getting ouput:

```
df_melted = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['SAP ID'], value_vars=df.columns.tolist())
```

Output:
[image]

Is there anyway through which this can be achieved?

Comment: If you provide python code for your example data (instead of screenshots or simple description), it's easier for people to reproduce your problem and you are more likely to get a useful answer

Comment: Added the code with the data as well.

Answer (score 1):

There might be more elegant solution but if you just copy your column to appear twice and the melt the data, you get your desired output:

```
df['SAP ID copy'] = df['SAP ID']

out = df.melt('SAP ID copy').rename(columns={'SAP ID copy': 'SAP ID'})
print(out)
```

```
    SAP ID     variable    value
0  MATSAP1       SAP ID  MATSAP1
1  MATSAP2       SAP ID  MATSAP2
2  MATSAP1  DESCRIPTION    DESC1
3  MATSAP2  DESCRIPTION    DESC2
4  MATSAP1        BASIC      BD1
5  MATSAP2        BASIC      BD2
6  MATSAP1         LINK      MD1
7  MATSAP2         LINK      MD2
```

OR

```
df = df.set_index('SAP ID',drop=False).stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['SAP ID', 'variable', 'value']
out = df.sort_values('variable').reset_index(drop=True)
print(out)
```

```
    SAP ID     variable    value
0  MATSAP1        BASIC      BD1
1  MATSAP2        BASIC      BD2
2  MATSAP1  DESCRIPTION    DESC1
3  MATSAP2  DESCRIPTION    DESC2
4  MATSAP1         LINK      MD1
5  MATSAP2         LINK      MD2
6  MATSAP1       SAP ID  MATSAP1
7  MATSAP2       SAP ID  MATSAP2
```

Comment: Thanks.  But, SAP ID column and its values should also be present in the variable and value columns. Please see the screenshot of the desired output.

Comment: @Deluxplanet345 Did my answer solve your problem?